# Delete the old data in the Oracle Data base

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, sql-delete

I am new guy to data base i would like to need a help from you buddies.

I want to  delete the row in the Oracle data base except the recent data

For example :
Delete the data's up-to yesterday and don't want to delete the today's data in the data base .

Consider a table which has 5 rows ,in that 2 rows added recently(today).I want that 2 rows should be unchanged and delete the remaining two rows.

```
A B C- Row

D   1 2 3 - old data

E   4 5 6 - old data

F   7 8 9 - old data

G   3 2 1 - New data Entered today

H   6 3 2 - New data Entered today
```

I would like to delete the row (**D ,E and F**).Data that was entered today wont be deleted it should remain unchanged.

Can any one please help me with these?

Comment: Sounds easy to filter the entries that is not updated today. What have you tried ?

Comment: Does your row have a column which identifies when the row was created?

Comment: how did you specify which data belongs to which date?

Answer (score 0):

> Consider a table which has 5 rows ,in that 2 rows added recently(today)

When you say "today", I assume you have a **DATE** column in your table to exactly tell when a row was **inserted**.

Let's take a simple example to understand how you would delete the old rows in your table.

Say I have a table `t`:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

     EMPNO ENAME          DEPTNO EDATE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------
      7369 SMITH              20 03-MAR-15
      7499 ALLEN              30 03-MAR-15
      7521 WARD               30 03-MAR-15
      7566 JONES              20 04-MAR-15
      7654 MARTIN             30 04-MAR-15
      7698 BLAKE              30 02-MAR-15
      7782 CLARK              10 02-MAR-15
      7788 SCOTT              20 02-MAR-15
      7839 KING               10 02-MAR-15
      7844 TURNER             30 02-MAR-15
      7876 ADAMS              20 02-MAR-15
      7900 JAMES              30 02-MAR-15
      7902 FORD               20 02-MAR-15
      7934 MILLER             10 02-MAR-15

14 rows selected.
```

Now I want to **delete** the rows which are older than today's date. Today's date is:

```
SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE
---------
04-MAR-15
```

Now there's a catch here, **sysdate** will have **datetime** element. So, you need to be specific whether you want only the truncated date portion or do you want to keep it with the time portion as well.

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM
-------------------
03/04/2015 10:24:17

SQL>
```

So, simply using SYSDATE would filter all the rows which have date value less than SYSDATE. You need to use **TRUNC** to make sure the rows are filtered on basis of the date portion and not considering the time portion.

```
SQL> DELETE FROM t WHERE edate < TRUNC(SYSDATE);

12 rows deleted.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

     EMPNO ENAME          DEPTNO EDATE
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------
      7566 JONES              20 04-MAR-15
      7654 MARTIN             30 04-MAR-15
```

There you go, older rows with respect to date are now deleted. Remaining rows are which were inserted today.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lalit Kumar B

But i don't have the column  which have date.

is there any way to delete this?

thanks

Comment: Then you need to provide the table details. What are the columns? What is the RULE to filter the rows to be deleted?